# How to use variable's value as HTTP POST parameter?

Tags: python, python-requests

I am trying to send HTTP post request to an API, but instead of using preset text values as POST data, I am trying to use the variables, but can't seems to figure out how to do this?

This is the code:

```
url1 = "https://example.com/api/req"
headers = CaseInsensitiveDict()
headers["Content-Type"] = "application/json"
data = """
{
    "type": "Direction",
    "station": "Dept",
    "status": "check",
    "values": {
        "Par1": "5",
        "Par2" : "2",
        "Par3": "3",
        "Par4": "1",
        "Par5": "4"
    }
}
"""
resp1 = requests.post(url1, headers=headers, data=data)
```

So Instead of using the something like `"type": "Direction"` I am trying to use `"type": Variable_1`.

How can one achieve this?

Comment: Remove the """'s that are turning your code into comments and it will work

Comment: @CaiAllin , if I remove """ then it gives me the  Invalid Syntax error

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use an f-string (as long as you are using Python 3.7+).

```
url1 = "https://example.com/api/req"
headers = CaseInsensitiveDict()
headers["Content-Type"] = "application/json"
Variable_1 = "Direction"
data = f"""
{{
    "type": "{Variable_1}",
    "station": "Dept",
    "status": "check",
    "values": {{
        "Par1": "5",
        "Par2" : "2",
        "Par3": "3",
        "Par4": "1",
        "Par5": "4"
    }}
}}
"""
resp1 = requests.post(url1, headers=headers, data=data)
```

Answer (score 2):

As @CaiAllin points out, you can just pass requests a Python dictionary like this:

```
import json
import requests
from requests.structures import CaseInsensitiveDict

url1 = "https://example.com/api/req"
headers = CaseInsensitiveDict()
headers["Content-Type"] = "application/json"

type_ = "Direction"
station = "Dept"
status = "check"
values = {
    "Par1": "5",
    "Par2": "2",
    "Par3": "3",
    "Par4": "1",
    "Par5": "4",
}

data = {
    "type": type_,
    "station": station,
    "status": status,
    "values": values,
}

resp1 = requests.post(url1, headers=headers, data=json.dumps(data))
```

Comment: this also gives an Error {'code': 'rest_invalid_json', 'message': 'Invalid JSON body passed.', 'data': {'status': 400, 'json_error_code': 4, 'json_error_message': 'Syntax error'}}

Comment: That's my bad, you need to dump the dict to json first. Amended my answer.

Comment: So now you're **not** passing a Python dictionary directly to `requests`, which is actually what @Cai Allin claimed would work and you had originally — i.e. you were both wrong about that merely being all that it takes. I also note that the [documentation](https://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/api/#requests.post) for `requests.post()` does not indicate that the `data` argument can be a JSON string (although there **is** a `json` argument that can be).

Comment: @martineau `requests.post` can take a regular python dictionary. That is if you want to post **form data**. If you want to post json encoded data, you can either dump it to json yourself and pass it to the `data` argument, or you can let requests do the encoding by passing a dictionary to the `json` argument (like the [documentation](https://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/user/quickstart/#more-complicated-post-requests) does, in fact, suggest). OP didn't specify what kind of data he needed to send, and I didn't think about it very hard, so I made a small error (20 hours ago).

Comment: Seems like using the `json` parameter would be better because then you wouldn't have to encode the `dict` yourself (as that your documentation link states). Regardless of how the dictionary gets passed, the whole approach seems more convoluted than necessary because of its use of multiple levels of indirection to accomplish what the OP wants to do.

Comment: @martineau Bro, OP accepted a different answer like a day ago, who cares? Use the json parameter if you really want to.